# Delphi. Метод для чтения/записи свойства-массива в классе

Tags: delphi

Разрабатываю класс, который работает с одномерным динамическим массивом объектов другого класса.

Т.е.

```
private
aMassive: array of TCar;
```

Мне нужно создать методы для модификации свойства класса. Делаю так:

```
function GetMassive(): array of TCar; // Здесь ошибка E2029 Identifier expected but 'ARRAY' found
function SetMassive(): array of TCar;

// Определяем СВОЙСТВА класса
property Massive[Index: integer]: array of TCar read GetMassive()
  write SetMassive();
```

Компилятор говорит мне, что ожидается идентификатор. Но почему он не принимает мою конструкцию `array of TCar`? Подскажите грамотный подход к решению.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array`  - не идентификатор, а служебное слово. 
Нужно объявить тип, например,

```
type
  TCarArray = array of TCar;
```

Вот `TCarArray` является идентификатором типа, и уже его использовать для описания типа результата, возвращаемого функцией, для описания типа поля

```
aMassive: TCarArray;
function GetMassive(): TCarArray;
```

---

В современных версиях Delphi модно использовать generic версию динамических массивов, в таком случае предварительное объявление типа не нужно

```
aMassive: TArray<TCar>;
```

Comment: `type
  TCarArray = array of TCar;` - данная конструкция должна быть обязательно членом текущего класса? Быть в секции private она может?

Comment: Типы вообще можно объявлять в секции private, но тогда ими, естественно, можно пользоваться только внутри класса. Наличие свойства подразумевает, что другие классы и модули должны знать тип свойства. Просто объявите его до объявления класса, в начале interface секции

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, массивы применительно к объектам не стоит использовать. Лучше создать список или коллекцию. Посмотрите, например, как реализован класс TFieldList. Там всё довольно прозрачно и несложно сделать по аналогии. Как вариант - используйте дженерики.